# Como instalar "font awesome" en angular2 con angular-cli?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, font-awesome

Cual sería la forma de agregar "Font Awesome" a un proyecto con Angular2 construido con anguar-cli? El objetivo no es utilizar el CDN de font awesome.

Comment: Revisa esto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796541/how-to-add-font-awesome-to-angular-2-cli-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es bastante simple, solo tienes que instalar la dependencia por medio de `npm` de la siguiente forma:

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

Luego en tu archivo *angular-cli.json* debes enlazar los estilos de la siguiente forma dentro del `arreglo` *styles*

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" // Aquí añades tu css desde la carpeta node_modules
],
```

Comment: Tienes que añadir el addon, para que funcione correctamente:
"addons": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*.+(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)"
],